# The transition animation on Navigator.push lags for a split second at the end

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-navigation

The transition to the new page, lags for a few miliseconds right before the end. It is most noticeably when using slide transition. It seems that the content of this new page doesn't really matter, as this lag is also present, even if this page is blank.
I've found the very [similar issue on Github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/31059), but those solutions didn't work

Comment: Have you tried running on  release mode? Try  `flutter run --release`

Comment: Yes, i've tried. It's a little bit better, but the lag is still there